# Recursion in python3

Tags: python-3.x

```
def r(s):

    if s=="":
        return ""
    else:
        return r(s[1:])+s[0]


r("ollah")
```

why is only s[0] returned and r(s[1:]) not? 
can someone explian this Code to me?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. It reverses the string.

Answer (score 2):

Your code in the form presented in your question works correctly. (Maybe you don't express your question accordingly.) So I will jump into the explanation:

I want to reverse a string (e.g.`"abcde"`). I may do it in this manner:

1. I divide this string into 2 parts:

   1. the first character (`a`) — I will call it a **head**, and
   2. the remaining characters (`bcde`) — I will call it a **tail**.

[image]

2. Then I simply:

   1. reverse the **tail** by some "magic" function `r()`- I will obtain `edcb`, and
   2. append the **head** to it — I will obtain `edcba`, a thing, what I wanted.

[image]

Written in Python (in a detailed form):

```
head = s[0]               # first character (of the string s)
tail = s[1:]              # second character to last character (of the same string)

reversedTail = r(tail)    # use of a "magical" function r()

reversedString = reversedTail + head
```

It doesn't matter if I perform it in a compact, one-line form

```
revesedString = r(s[1:]) + s[0]      # reversed tail appended by head
```

---

**Now the “only” problem is how to reverse the tail!**

But while string `"abcde"` had **5** characters, the **tail** `"bcde"` has only **4** of them.

To reverse `bcde`, I will follow the same idea:

1. I divide it into a **head** (`b`) and a **tail** (`cde`), then 
   [image]
2. I reverse the **tail** by the “magical” function `r()` to obtain `edc`, and append the **head** (`b`).
   [image]

The result will be `edcb` — exactly what I wanted.

---

Here raised a similar problem — how to reverse now only **3**-character long string `"cde"`?

The solution is the same: dividing into a **head** (`c`) and a **tail** (`de`), reversing the **tail** and append the **head** to it. The result: `edc`, what I wanted.

---

But how to reverse **2**-character long string `"de"`? You already know — by dividing it into a **head** (`d`) and a **tail** (`e`), reversing the tail and append the head to it, obtaining `ed`.

---

**Now the most difficult task — how to reverse the 1-character long string `"e"`?**

You know — dividing it into a **head** (`e`) and a **tail** — but the **tail** is now an *empty string* (`""`). By reverting an empty string we obtain the same empty string, which is in your program expressed as

```
if s=="":
    return ""
```

So the "magical" function is not as magical as it seems - it relies on dividing the original string into a **head** and a **tail**, and then recursively on dividing the **tail** into another **head** and **tail**. The last **tail** is an *empty string*, and the recursion ends here. (From the other point of view, the computation just begins.)

Only the **tail** is passed (as an input parameter) to the magical function `r()` (in the form `return r(tail) + head`) — progressively shorter and shorter:

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: Can I say that the first alphabet is added to the last position und the length of the string reduce 1 after every recursion? 
Very clear explanation. Thanks